# MonoTouch.Dialog StyledStringElement Hidden

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is there a way to hide and show a `StyledStringElement` in MonoTouch.Dialog?

I have only found `Dispose()`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 4):

You do not hide an `Element` by itself. You add/insert them from a `Section` and remove them if you do not want them anymore.

You might also need to reload the `DialogViewController` to see the effect of adding/removing elements.